# How to create a stacked geom_bar with three columns of data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Looking for some help as to how to make a stacked bar plot using the following data:

```
DF <- data.frame(group = c("Pensioner", "Adult", "Teenager", "Child", "Toddler"),
                 Beach = c(30,20,35,10,5),
                 Park = c(40,15,20,25,10))
```

This is completely fictitious data, with values representing the percentage of people in each age class who were at the two locations. I just wish to understand how to make this sort of plot.

I am looking to make a plot with the x axis containing the labels 'beach' and 'park' with the fill representing the different values for each age group, which would feature in the legend. Essentially one which looks like this:

[image: Graph]

I have tried some coding with melt, but haven't quite got it right:

```
R_Edits.m <- melt(R_Edits,id.vars = "Group")

AgeSite <- ggplot(R_Edits.m, aes(x=Group, y=value, fill=Variable)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position ="stack")
```

This produces a stacked barplot, but instead with the group at the bottom as opposed to being the fill,  and I am unsure how to reorganise this appropriately.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Switch Variable and Group, i.e.`ggplot(R_Edits.m, aes(x=Variable, y=value, fill=Group))`?

Comment: Aha! Thank you. That was actually such a simple fix, I followed someone else's code for this so I hadn't played around with switching them.

Comment: @stefan I'm quite late but you should post your answer as an answer, not as a comment!